# Is there a built-in function in php which can return first row of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, built-in

I need to access the first row of an array but not like this:

```
print_r($array[0]) ;
```

something like this and be **built-in** :

```
echo first($array) ;
```

is there anything like that in php?

Comment: [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) or even [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array-shift).

Comment: What's wrong with using `$array[0]`? That is the proper syntax.

Comment: @MikeW array might be empty, so this might enforce E_NOTICE issue. Another walkaround is `count($array) ? $array[0] : false`.

Comment: `$array[0]` is not always present. How do you get the first element from `array('randomstring'=>'value')`?

Comment: I need it because the array is return value of a function and PHP version less than 5.4
echo reset($this->class->func($arg1,..)) ; it will retrieve in a row but with indexing
$array=$this->class->func($arg1,..); echo $array[0];
there's 2 lines. I just need one.

Comment: how about [`list()`](http://php.net/list) construction ? `list($a, $b,  $c) = array(1,2,3); var_dump($a, $b, $c);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reset($array)` will move the internal array pointer to the first element and return that element as well.

Note that "the first element" not necessarily means the element with index 0. It means the first element that got added to the array:

```
$array[1] = "foo";
$array[0] = "bar";
$first = reset($array); // foo
```

You might want to sort the array before fetching the "first" element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$first_value_of_array = reset($array); // First Element's Value
$first_key_of_array = key($array); // First Element's Key
```

Hope this helps. :)